# Query ain't working on data lookup

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query!
Why isn't it working?

```
   $start=$_REQUEST['to'];
$end=$_REQUEST['from'];
echo $start1 = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($start));
echo $end1 = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($end));

echo $data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr
WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN '$start1' AND '$end1';
")
```

I mean the output of $date_get is: 20121203 , it's supposed to work. it works if i set:

```
echo $data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr
WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN'20121201' AND '20121203';
")
```

Comment: In which format `calldate` is being stored in DB?

Comment: use someting like (BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$end1')

Comment: can you show how it is being stored in DB? i mean example of `calldate`

Comment: i'm sorry, is datetime type..

Comment: looks mth like this :2012-12-01 14:23:03

Comment: Use of the `mysql_*` extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. Don't believe me? Check out the red box at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

[strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) `Returns a string formatted according format using the given timestamp`. So put quotes in first query and get result like this

```
echo $data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr
WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN '$start1' AND '$end1';
");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace this:

```
$data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr 
        WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN $start1 AND $end1;");
```

with this

```
$data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr 
        WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN '$start1' AND '$end1'");
```

The final code without echo:

```
$start=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($_REQUEST['to']));
$end=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($_REQUEST['from']));

$data = mysql_query( "select * from cdr
    WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
```

Comment: this won't work... i don't know.. could you please see the updated question?
The calldate is datetime type

Comment: because there is semicolon at the end of $end1 var we dont need it there.

Answer (score 1):

Use


`BETWEEN '$start1' AND '$end1'` 


or you can use 

`where DATE(calldate) >= "$start1" and DATE(calldate) =< "$end1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $start1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
   $end1   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end));

 "SELECT * from `cdr` 
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cont_msg_received_dt,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$start1."' AND '".$end1."' "
```

Comment: are you telling without checking?